# How to search for a specific word in nodejs and return the coloun number

Tags: regex, node.js, excel

I am trying to find out where the source ip colon is there in the excel file i want it to search in the whole file rather than me manually telling in  the code .

How to do it i want to know weather there is possibility  and any modules available for that work

My nodejs code

```
    var Regex = require("regex");
    var regex = new Regex(/(S|s)(O|o)(U|u)(R|r)(C|c)(E|e)( )*(I|i)(P|p)/);
    var parseXlsx = require('excel');

    parseXlsx('ISFWREQ-373_update.xlsx', function(err, data) {


    console.log(regex.test(data[5][0]));

    });
```

Comment: what do you hope the regex to match ?

Comment: I suggest this approach: use `/^[\s\S]*?source *ip/i` regex to match all text from the beginning up to the nearest "source ip", and then split the result with `\n` to get the line number with `m[0].split(/\n/).length`. Here is a piece of code for you to test: `if ((m = /^[\s\S]*?source *ip/i.exec('Line 1\nLine 1\nLine 1\nLine source ipLine 1Line 1\n')) !== null) {
    alert(m[0].split(/\n/).length);
}`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @aelor i want data in the colon source ip only so i want regex to match and the source ip will be there in every file i will get in same format

Comment: @stribizhev i am getting an output of 4 for every file i am inputting can you explain the code or reference

Comment: `'Line 1\nLine 1\nLine 1\nLine source ipLine 1Line 1\n'` is my example string. You must replace it with the file contents, and please retry.